# visual studio 2015 can't with c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: screenshot of my installation]

I am installing Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem then relocate this (vc_runtimeAdditional_x64) file. click to Browse Button and enter your path.

It would be in Package folder. In my case the path of this folder is H:\VS\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64, Where H: = drive, VS = my Visual studio folder where i have all files.